# Шпаргалка по регулярным выражениям PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть у кого-нибудь шпаргалка по регулярным выражениям PHP в виде картинки на русском. Или просто страничка, где без лишней воды, где простым языком описаны все символы (разделители, модификаторы и т.д.).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[https://www.google.ru/search?q=Шпаргалка+по+регулярным+выражениям+PHP](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC+PHP)

Таким способом сразу же нашел [image]

Comment: Блин, а я что-то только на английском находил. Спасибо!