# С помощью регулярного выражения удалить повторяющиеся буквы

Tags: c#

Задача:

Необходимо написать программу, которая удалит одинаковые, рядом стоящие символы из произвольной строки. При этом, если при удалении этих символов опять появится 
пара одинаковых рядом стоящих символов, то они тоже должны удалиться. Вот несколько тестов для проверки:

```
/*balloon -> ban
  book -> bk
  affah -> h
  essence -> nce
  void Main()*/
{
    var src =
    @"balloon-ban
    book-bk
    affah-h
    essence-nce";

    var lines = src.Split('\n');

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var words = line.Trim().Split('-');
        Debug.Assert(Foo(words[0]) == words[1], $"Foo({words[0]}) return:               
        {
            Foo(words[0])}, excpected: {words[1]}");
        }
    }

string Foo(string s)
{
     s = Regex.Replace(s,@"\S{2}","");
     return s;
}
```

Мой метод удаляет все повторяющиеся символы, не могу подобрать нужный шаблон

Comment: Попробуйте `\S{2,}`

Comment: `\S{2,}` так же как `\S{2}` удаляет все повторяющиеся, т.е. и символы b и a и n, в тех случаях где они должны остаться

Comment: Справочник вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/236948/17974

Comment: Возьмем строку `abaabc` что от нее должно остаться ?

Comment: @Mike, по условию - `ac`.  То есть: `$s =~ s/(.)\1+//g while $s =~ /(.)\1/;`

Comment: @PinkTux Ну на perl то цикл совершенно не к чему `(\S)(?0)*\1+` https://regex101.com/r/zICN87/1 Но вот как рекурсию перевести на C# движок не понимаю. вернее пока не понял как она вообще в C# работает (пишут что есть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно сделать так, с циклом, который прервётся, как только очередная замена ничего не изменит:

```
string Foo(string s){
    string p;
    do {
        p = s;
        s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(.)\1+", "");
    } while (s != p);
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Да. без цикла остаются повторяющиеся символы, которые появились после замены уже