# Регулярные выражения в C#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите как найти все разные слова в тексте или хотя бы идею подайте. Ничего в голову не лезет

Comment: Справка по регулярке вот http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236947/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-php

Comment: А зачем регулярка? `string.Split` по разделителям и `Distinct` результат.

Comment: @Vlad, а какие именно символы являются разделителями?

Comment: @nick_n_a, в C# могут отличаться конструкции

Comment: @Qwertiy, знаки препинания, пробелы, тире, скобки.

Answer (score 6):

http://ideone.com/AH5jHw

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var s = "One thing is not the other one, even if it is one";
    var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"\b\w+\b").OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", res));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace First_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Text = "Привет, мой друг! Я очень надеюсь, что данный пример тебе помог. ДрУг, Запомни, что 2*2=4, а 3-1=\"2\"";
            List<string> result = Text.ToLower().Split(new string[] { " ", "/", "*", ".", "=", "!", "-", "\"", "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

1) Вам нужны слова, поэтому используйте .ToLower, чтобы уйти от зависимости к регистру.

2) В массиве new string[] укажите разделители, которые Вам не нужны.

Comment: Разделителей много. По-моему, `\b` в регулярках надёжнее.

Comment: Вот тут я с Вами готов поспорить. Регулярка, которая использована в качестве ответа ниже не учтёт первого и последнего слова в предложении. С примерной работой данного выражения Вы можете ознакомиться по ссылке [Регулярные выражения С#](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level4/4_10.php)

Comment: Как это не учтёт? Там же пример на ideone есть. Первое слово `One` есть в результате, последнего нет, т. к. оно встречается раньше. http://ideone.com/MWzE1C - вот, все слова на месте.

Comment: Результат содержит слово "one", поскольку оно встретилось в середине предложения.

Comment: Я же ещё одну ссылку дал в комментарии - там 3 разных слова и все 3 попали в результат. А в примере в ответе есть `One`, который был первым и `one`, который был в середине - у них разный регистр. Последнего `one` нет, т. к. он повторяет центральный. Ну и чтобы делать без учёта регистра можно добавить `.ToLower()` либо к исходной строке, либо к `m.Value`.

Comment: И всё - таки Split позволяет более гибко доставать слова.

Comment: [Результат работы на ideone](http://ideone.com/AfWl9P)

Comment: Подчёркивания традиционно считаются буквами. Но если очень хочется, то можно так: http://ideone.com/XKRxW8

Comment: По моему наш спор превращается в борьбу вкусов и подходов. Думаю, мы предоставили автору вопроса альтернативу выбора.