# Регулярные выражение. Циркумфлекс

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Что делает циркумфлекс, помещенный в квадратные скобки?
`[^"]`

Comment: Мне кажется, что описание как работает регулярка, должно быть как-то собрано в одном вопросе. На en версии всё тут http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics на ru тут неплохое описание http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236947/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-php

Comment: @nick_n_a, `stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/topics` – ну так это «[Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation)», новый раздел SO. У него совершенно другой формат.

Comment: @nick_n_a, плюс в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/236947/208074 не указано, что циркумфлекс в диапазонах не экранируется и воспринимается как есть (иными словами, является литералом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вся конструкция означает: «Любой символ кроме кавычки».

При этом циркумфлекс должен стоять *в начале* строки, в противном случае он будет воспринят как полноценный символ в перечислении. К примеру, `["^]` будет уже означать «Либо кавычка («"»), либо циркумфлекс («^»)».

- [Пример  с «^» в начале](https://regex101.com/r/YiU2JY/1).
- [Пример  с «^» **не** в начале](https://regex101.com/r/PL8jcy/1).