# Какие виды regex поддерживаются браузерами?

Tags: javascript, webbrowser

Я столкнулся с тем, что regex в браузере отрабатывает не совсем так как в c# php и других средах. 
  Вопрос, все ли регулярные выражения работают в браузерах?
  Те которые работают без вопросов (не все, те которые чуть сложнее): `??` `+?` `*?` `{...}?` `[^..]` отработали хорошо.

Приведу те, которые вызвали вопросы

1. Утверждения `?<=`  `?<!` (получаю syntax error)
2. Условные `?(число)` `?(число)|`  `?(условие)` `?(условие)|` (не вижу захвата, работает `/(12)(?(1)3)/`  как не распознало выражение - ничего не захватывает).

Справку по regex брал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236947/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-php).
По-поводу версионности regex не удалось найти информацию. Всё-таки, в какой степени браузеры поддерживают regex? Что можно использовать, а что нельзя?

На что стоит рассчитывать, на что не стоит? Огласите полный перечень.

Answer (score 2):

Это не к браузерам, это [к стандартам на JavaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.5). Как вы правильно заметили, в JS нет привычных назад смотрящих выражений вида `?<=`. Так и нет многострочного режима. Нет определений для блоков Уникода. Из важного.

Ситуация усложняется тем что нет какого-то такого универсального на все времена стандарта на регулярные выражения. Даже если вы возьмете [стандарт на регулярные выражения POSIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html) в его расширенном виде, то вы увидите что там тоже все несколько не так, как в привычных вам PCRE. Если же копнуть глубже общего вида регулярных выражений, [то откроется бездна](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10251973/93540).

Если вы посмотрите на другие языки программирования, [то у них будут свои особенности](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). Такая жизнь. Не стоит рассчитывать и вообще ждать что ваши регулярки будут работать везде.

Comment: Жизнь - боль...

Comment: Я ожидал ответ, например, что в JavaScript браузеров работают точно (список) выражений. Ведь в конечном счёте, разработчика интерисует - чем он располагает.

Comment: Тогда вам надо переформулировать вопрос более конкретно.