# Что экранировать в квадратных скобках рег. выражения

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает регулярка?

Срабатывает если появляется хоть один посторонний символ кроме:

букв, цифр, пробела и следующих знаков `.` `,` `;` `=` `+` `-` `/` `(` `)` `!`

```
reg = /[^A-Za-z 0-9_А-Яа-я\.\,\;\=\+\-\/\(\)\!]+/;
```

Не нашел нигде что нужно экранировать внутри квадратных скобок?

Comment: Найдите справку по regex. Управляющие символы зачем нужны? Что будет если управляющий символ указан - управляющие символы нужно екранировать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions

Comment: справка https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236947/%D0%A8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подправил регулярку, убрал лишние экраны и добавил игнорирование регистра, в квадратных скобках экранировать нужно только сами скобки `[]`, слэши `\/` и знак диапазона `-`. Так же в кириллице надо добавлять `ё` отдельно.

В хроме всё работает:

```js
console.log(/[^a-z 0-9_а-яё.,;=+\-\/()!]+/i.test(' АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.,;=+-/()!'))
```

Comment: p.s. забыл добавить, что в регулярном выражении `a-z0-9_` лучше сразу заменить на `\w`, а пробел на `\s` дабы отловить все пробельные символы, в том числе табуляцию, `&nbsp;`, перенос строки, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум попробуйте экранировать точку, знаки плюса, минуса, восклицательный знак и круглые скобки (все это спецсимволы). Также у вас не совсем верное выражение в плане кириллического диапазона, пропущена буква "ё", которую надо задавать отдельно (она не входит в диапазон). В общем, лучше сделать так:

```
reg = /[^a-zа-яё0-9 _\.\,\;\=\+\-\/\(\)\!]+/i;
```

Comment: Нашел типа вот такой таблички https://www.megaindex.org/regulyarnyie_vyirajeniya_v_google_analytics Знаки которые нужно экранировать Metacharacters (must tby escaped). Спасибо кто откликнулся.

Comment: @VitVlad в принципе да, но лучше экранировать все символы в отношении которых могут быть сомнения (как там написано, это то, что поддерживает google analytics, а могут быть и другие системы, где поддержка регулярных выражений может отличаться от этой таблицы).